# Triggering false sense of stimulus

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, perception

When I pinch my right upper inner thigh I get a tingling sensation on my right upper forearm (on the inner side (near the place my forearm is touching the desk as I type)). I have had similar experiences with stimulus on different regions of the body.

My questions:

- How can this be understood in terms of how the different parts of my body are stored in my brain, knowing that perhaps the stimulus signal is also activating the nearby forearm responsible region?
- Does this imply that in my evolutionary history my inner thigh and forearm were one(ie femur and radius were one) and that they have since split to form separate limbs, or perhaps just the skin covering those regions was once close and has since split, hence largely sharing the same neural pathways? If so, can this distant past still have such an impact on my perception and senses that I am attributing to it?
- What is the best explanation as to why these two regions are stored closely together in the brain, if so is the case?
- Have any prominent studies been done on this phenomenon?